# Может ли Service иметь репозитории других классов?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Допустим у меня есть `Entity A` и `Entity B`. Могу ли я прямо обратиться к репозиторию `Entity A` из `Service B`?
Или мне надо это делать вот так `Service B -> Service A -> Repository A`?

Проблема в том, что у меня в сервисе DTOшки, а для работы `Service B` нужны нормальные объекты, что делать в таком случае?

Comment: Что значит _все сервисы DTOшки_??  Это немного разные вещи -- сервисы обеспечивают некую обработку данных, _которые_ могут быть представлены в виде DTO (Data Transfer Object).

Comment: В целом на такой вопрос нельзя дать объективный ответ, в сервисе B может быть либо ссылка на репозиторий RepoA, либо на сервис ServiceA, либо сервис B может обращаться к какому-нибудь `ServiceLocator`, который возвращал бы ссылку на сервис ServiceA, в зависимости от _ваших_ потребностей.

Comment: @AlexRudenko прошу прощения, оговорился. Сервисы возвращают дтошки

Comment: Сервис может использовать какие угодно другие сервисы и репозитарии. Да и какой смысл, если репозиторий прячется за своим сервисом? В такой ситуации имеется лишняя сущность (не путать с ентити) либо сервис лишний, либо репозиторий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не только можете, но именно так и стОит делать. Нежелательно, чтобы сервисы одного слоя зависели друг от друга, иначе с ростом проекта непременно полезут круговые зависимости